# Entity Framework Parallel One-to-Many Relationship

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I've been looking around to try to create a parallel one-to-many relationship in EF. Heres what I mean:

I've got two classes, Transaction and User:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string ExecutorID { get; set; }
    public virtual User Executor { get; set; }

    public string ConsumerID { get; set; }
    public virtual User Consumer { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public UserRole Role { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Pin { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Transaction> ExecutedTransactions { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; } 
}
```

If you haven't seen it already, I've got two links between the objects, `Transactions` and `Executed Transactions`. My question is how can I tell EF to differentiate between the two?

Transactions should point to all `Transaction` where `User.ID == Transaction.ConsumerID` and `ExecutedTransactions` where `User.ID == Transaction.ExecutorID`

Comment: What the end result would be that you expect in the database? 4 tables of Users, Customers, Transactions and ExecutedTransactions OR 3 tables of Users, Customers, Transactions ?

Comment: In this model, users and customers need to be the same, as a user can also be a customer. I was hoping for two tables. Users and Transactions. I'm thinking I could solve the problem by doing the linq manually, but I was wondering if it could be done using a mechanism of EF

Comment: I would suggest you create an abstract class of Transaction, then derive 2 concrete classes that are ConsumerTransaction and ExecutorTransaction, that way EF will automatically create a single table with a `Discriminator` column, and in the application you don't need to filter manually

Comment: Ohhh I like it... I'm going to run with that. I'll report back.

Comment: I'll show you an example..

Comment: So is it not possible to do this in the EF with just 2 tables?  Does the EF not allow 2 foreign keys to the same table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the classes where `Food` and `Book` are derived from `Item`.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Food> Foods { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
public abstract class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Food : Item
{
    public int CookedById { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CookedById")]
    public Person CookedBy { get; set; }
}
public class Book : Item
{
    public int AuthorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("AuthorId")]
    public Person Author { get; set; }
}
```

**Option A Table Per Hierarchy**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Foods).WithRequired(f => f.CookedBy).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Result would be **2 tables**, table `Person` and `Item` that has automatically `Discriminator` column that will be filled with `Food` and `Book`.

To query you need to filter from `Items` by its type.

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var foods = context.Items.Where(item => item is Food).ToArray();
    var books = context.Items.Where(item => item is Book).ToArray();
}
```

**Option B Table Per Concrete Class**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Foods).WithRequired(f => f.CookedBy).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Result would be **3 tables**, table `Person`, `Food` and `Book`.

To query you can directly take from Foods and Books.

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
    var foods = context.Foods.ToArray();
    var books = context.Books.ToArray();
}
```

**Option C Table Per Type**

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(p => p.Foods).WithRequired(f => f.CookedBy).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Food>().ToTable("Foods");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Book>().ToTable("Books");
    }
}
```

Result would be **4 Tables**, table `Person`, `Item`, `Food` and `Book`. Table `Food` and `Book` will have relationship to table `Ttem`.

The query is the same like Table Per Hierarchy.