# Table Per Type Fluent Mapping in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With Entity Framework I can map related tables as a class inheritance and There are three different approaches to representing an inheritance hierarchy (by [weblogs](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)):

- Table per Hierarchy (TPH)
- Table per Type (TPT)
- Table per Concrete class (TPC)

The site mscblogs has a nice explanation for each one of these approaches.

I'm trying to understand how to map my tables using the approach TPT (Table per Type), but unlike the example of [mscblogs](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt), I need to do the mapping for fluent programming like:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;

public class BillingDetailMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BillingDetailEntity>
{
    public BillingDetailMap()
    {
        // ...
        this.Property(t => t.Number).HasColumnName("Number");
        // ...
    }    
}

// ...
```

I'm searching for several hours but I couldn't find anything. I found many examples how to do this with [diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618292.aspx), with [attributes](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt) and [others](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/393228/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Inheritance-Table-Per), but nothing with fluent api.

**How to Mapping TPT in Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mapping the Table-Per-Type (TPT) Inheritance**

> In the TPT mapping scenario, all types are mapped to individual
>   tables. Properties that belong solely to a base type or derived type
>   are stored in a table that maps to that type. Tables that map to
>   derived types also store a foreign key that joins the derived table
>   with the base table.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");  
modelBuilder.Entity<OnsiteCourse>().ToTable("OnsiteCourse");
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.5)

Check also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25016385/968303) on previous question, hopefully it helps.

## update complete example

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; } // --> this dbset is required for TPT, if removed it will become TPCC
    public DbSet<Food> Books { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Foods { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ItemMap());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BookMap());
    }
}
public class ItemMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Food>
{
    public ItemMap()
    {
        ToTable("Foods");
    }
}
public class BookMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public BookMap()
    {
        ToTable("Books");
    }
}
public abstract class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Food : Item { }
public class Book : Item { }
```

Comment: Thaks for help but I need the map class (how/where set the Property, HasColumnName, ...), this code you posted is present in the examples listed in the question.

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi, do the same with `this.ToTable("BillingDetailEntities");` on the `BillingDetailMap` constructor